# cvxpy Portfolio Optimization

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, portfolio

I am trying to understand which is the best way to construct the parameters using the cvxpy engine.

I have seen this post:
[more of list-like](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39005/turnover-as-a-soft-constraint-for-portfolio-optimization) way of constructing constraints etc

and this post:
[more matrix-like notation](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/45954/how-to-calculate-optimal-portfolio-using-sector-constraints-in-python) way of constructing constraints etc.

I want to ask: is there any problem following either "notation" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is not difference but I would suggest using matrices as the optimization problems are more intuitive when looking at matrices. When I did this it helped to recognize what the diagonals of the matrix meant, etc. And for simple linear optimization Ax=b it is better to think of A as the matrix, and x and b as vectors (also matrices technically but whatever). Hope this helps. I would also use Python or R for these types of things. The optimizers are great in Python and I think it is more intuitive the inputs you will use